# Copy Excel Range Cells from a Multiple Worksheets then Save it as a Separate Files using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, worksheet

Good day :)
I'm trying to copy or reflect specific values of cells from a multiple Worksheet then save it as a Different Files without changing the Format/Look of that Output Excel File.

See the attached file of what I'm trying to do:
[input1_Sheet1 Cells being saved as output1_Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnqvq.png)
[input1_Sheet2 Cells being save as output2_Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t73P0.png)

This is my original Code:

```
<#### Declaring the FolderPaths as Variable for easier access ####>
$ParentFolder = "C:\root" # Root Folder
$Ouput = "$ParentFolder\output" # Destination Path
$Input = "$ParentFolder\input" # Source Path

# Get All matched Files
$InputFiles =  $ParentFolder | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where {$_.Name -match 'input'} | Where {$_.Extension -match '.xlsx'} #Check All the Input Files
$OutputFiles =  $ParentFolder | Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where {$_.Name -match 'output'} | Where {$_.Extension -match '.xlsx'} #Check All the Output Files

# For Every Matched Input Files
ForEach ($Files in $InputFiles)
{
     # Initialize the Excel App
     $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
     $Excel.visible = $false
     $Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false

     # Check the Input Files that has Worksheet named Sheet1
     $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Files.FullName)
     $FirstSheet = $WorkBook.WorkSheets | where {$_.name -eq "Sheet1"}
     
     # If the $FirstSheet has found "Sheet1"
     if ($FirstSheet) {

         #For the Output template File
         ForEach ($File in $OutputFiles) {
             $OpenOutput = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File.Fullname)
             $OutputSheet = $OpenOutput.WorkSheets.Item(1)

             # Copy the Selected Range from the Input File
             $SelectMulti =  $FirstSheet.Range("C6:C11")
             [void]$SelectMulti.Copy()

             # Paste to the Output File then Save it as a New File
             [void]$OpenOutput.worksheets.item(1).Range("B2:B7").PasteSpecial(-4163)
             [void]$OpenOutput.SaveAs("$Input\Output2_Sheet1.xlsx") # ERROR: Cannot access 'Output2_Sheet1.xlsx'
         }
     }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I moved the COM Object Outside the Loop, and now I can copy the files, and Showing No Error. I also put Close() on my workbook.

```
# Initialize the Excel App
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.visible = $false
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
```

```
[void]$OpenOutput.SaveAs("$OutputFolder\Output2_Sheet1.xlsx")
      $OpenOutput.Close()
```

I only have to work on my file naming as it was overwriting the Output Files. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Rule #1 when using COM objects: don't create an new Excel object again and again inside a loop. By doing this, you **will** run out of system resources.

Comment: I see! Thank you for this :) I can now copy the files and now I'm working on my SaveAs error.

Comment: I think you should [edit] your question and post the SaveAs error in there in full, so we can see what the problem might be. (While you're at it, also show us the revised code). As hint, choose a different name for variable `$Input`, because that is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#input) in PowerShell.

Comment: Hint [2]: Save your work, exit PowerShell and using the task manager kill all Excel instances now running. Then try the script again. Also, at the end of the script exit Excel and destroy the COM objects